# Data never gets written for a newly added column into an existing custom table in Log Analytics workspace

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

I'm using Azure Log Analytics Workspace with custom table and sending some data into this table based on this example code on [github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/azure-monitor-ingestion_1.0.1/sdk/monitor/azure-monitor-ingestion/samples/sample_send_small_logs.py) i.e., using log ingestion api and DCR etc.

Everything works fine. I can send data just fine except when I update this custom table and add a new column to it and then try to send the data against it.

The data gets written to the table for the previously defined columns but not for the newly added column, it never gets written. Looks like it being dropped or ignored.

For example;

1. Create table with this sample data

   {
   "rowid": "1112223334440000",
   "col1": "data1",
   "col2": "data2",
   "col3": "123"
   }
2. Send data based on the example code
3. Update table schema and now add col0
4. Send data again but now with col0 data .

I believe any new data entered in this log analytics table with col0 should now be populated but it doesn't in my case. I have tried multiple time, waited multiple hours but it never work for me.

Here is my code just in case;

```
import os
import json
from azure.core.exceptions import HttpResponseError
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.monitor.ingestion import LogsIngestionClient

endpoint = os.environ['DATA_COLLECTION_ENDPOINT']
credential = DefaultAzureCredential()

client = LogsIngestionClient(
    endpoint=endpoint, credential=credential, logging_enable=True)

rule_id = os.environ['LOGS_DCR_RULE_ID']
body = [
{
    "rowid": "1112223334440000",
    "col0": "data0",
    "col1": "data1",
    "col2": "data2",
    "col3": "123"
}
]

try:
        client.upload(rule_id=rule_id,
                  stream_name=os.environ['LOGS_DCR_STREAM_NAME'], logs=body)
except HttpResponseError as e:
        print(f"Upload failed: {e}")
```

Here is the table schema;

[image]

Can someone help explain why this is not working?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

- This behavior is expected because the schema for existing logs in the table is not automatically updated when you add a new column. As a result, the new column will not be populated with data for existing logs.
- Modifying or re-sending existing logs might affect the overall data and any analytics or queries that rely on the previous log structure.

I have tried the same code that which you performed.

[image]

Here we can see the column updated but the data was effected internally.

[image]

- Log Analytics tables are not intended for schema evolution in real-time. If you require schema flexibility and dynamic changes to the log structure, you may want to consider using Azure Data Explorer (ADX), which is a big data analytics platform that natively supports schema evolution.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue but was able to resolve it by following below steps,

Try to upload the new table JSON schema to DCR and then try to push the data and check. If this doesn't work, try the below options by following the steps,

**1. Go to DCR, search for Export Template**

[image]

**2. On the Export Template pane, Click on Deploy**

[image]

**3. Click on Edit Template, and check if the template contains your updated schema, if NO then add the new field in JSON schema and click on Create**

[image]

**4. Update the Custom Log Table Schema with the updated fields if it's not done already**

Came across this nice article which helped me resolve this issue,

[Demystifying Data Collection Rules and Transformations](https://hybridbrothers.com/demystifying-data-collection-rules-and-transformations/)